# Python - генерация случайных чисел в заданном соотношении

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Всем привет! Нужен скрипт который генерирует список из случайных чисел так чтобы во всем списке положительных чисел было в 2 раза больше отрицательных. Текущий вариант кода ниже.

```
import numpy as np

initial=10
npoints=5
upper=20
lower=20

a=[initial]
for b in range(npoints):
    value = np.random.randint(-(lower),upper)
    b=a[-1]+value
    a.append(b)
print(a)
```

Comment: Если диапазон в условии задан не жестко, то можно сделать диапазон например от -10 до 20 - тогда положительных чисел будет больше чем отрицательных примерно в 2 раза.

Comment: есть такой вариант, но будет ли корректен с точки зрения математики?

Comment: Смотря что вы подразумеваете под этим.

Comment: Как вариант - сделать нужное суммарное число чисел, все положительные. Потом взять индексы всех чисел, перемешать, из них отобрать нужную пропорцию, сделать числа по этим индексам отрицательными. Пропорция тогда будет чёткая.

Comment: Дополняю: Отобрать - в смысле взять срез `[:n]`, в чём и суть, что индексы уже перемешаны, можно просто взять нужное число индексов из начала перемешанного списка.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю заполнять только положительными числами, а потом сделать какое-то количество отрицательными.
Например, мы можем выбрать `npoints // 3` для вашего случая различных индексов с помощью `sample` из модуля `random` (перед этим нужно его импортировать, разумеется).

```
list_index = random.sample(range(0, len(a)-1), npoints // 3)
```

То есть выбрали `npoints // 3` различных индексов, присутствующих в списке `a`.
Затем меняем нужные нам элементы с помощью цикла.

```
for index in list_index:
     a[index] = -(a[index])
```